# allow [something] compute or to compute

Tags: grammar, writing

I have a sentence like:

> to allow the machine compute the...
>   Should it be: compute, or computes, or to compute?

Comment: It should be "to compute". It is possible to elide the prepostion - *to allow the machine compute...* - but this is not as common with *allow* as it would be with e.g. *let*, where a following infinitive would always exclude the *to* - *to let the machine compute the results*.

Comment: Hey, WS2! That's an interesting detail I'd never noticed before… if it's *allow the machine* to *compute*. 

I don't understand how *allow the machine compute* works.

Answer (score 1):

"to compute'

Because the machine isn't the subject of the sentence, you aren't going to say 'computes' like you would if it was. The infinitive is correct in this sentence.